# Preparing Report From three Tables

Tags: php

i m going to prepare a report from three tables in php .
the tables related to one another as Table A's primary key is a foreign key in Table B AND Table B's Primary Key is a foreign key in Table C .now i m going to select Data from table C and also from Table A. Table A And Table C are not directly Related to one another

Comment: Sougata exactly i m looking for JOINs

Comment: Hi, u should explain your conditions in a easy way (maybe with pictures and codes) so that others can come easily to help u. AN example question-

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32263145/sweep-line-algorithm-implementation-for-1d-plane/32263146#32263146

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query:

```
select * from A
inner join B on A.primary_key = B.Foreign_key
inner join C on B.primary_key = C.foreign_key

Here A.primary_key  = A's primary key
Here B.Foreign_key  = A's primary key in B's table
B.primary_key = B's primary key
C.foreign_key = B's primary key in C's table
```

Comment: If it solves your problem, please vote and mark the answer as correct.

Comment: i m trying. dont wory if it solves my problem i will mark it correct.